# Finding if a networkx graph is traceable in python

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I am trying to prove the following graph is traceable:

```
n = 50
nodes = range(1, n + 1)
graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_nodes_from(nodes)
for i in nodes:
    for j in nodes:
        if i != j and is_perfect_square(i + j):
            graph.add_edge(i, j)
```

I tried to find an algorithm on the internet, but it seems there is none. I tried [networkx.algorithms.tournament.hamiltonian_path](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/algorithms/tournament.html#hamiltonian_path) but it only works for directed graphs. So I had to settle on the following very inefficient solution:

```
def is_traceable(G):
    """
    :type G: nx.Graph
    """
    needed = len(G.nodes)
    for i in G.nodes:
        for j in G.nodes:
            for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, i, j):
                if len(path) == needed:
                    return True

    return False
```

This works well for `n <= 45` but from `n = 46` and on it takes a very long time to return. Why could that be, and how can I improve the efficiency such that the time will be reasonable for `n` in the hundreds?

Comment: According to the docs, the algorithms in `networkx.algorithms.tournament` only apply to tournament graphs, so they would not apply to your graph anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the graph is traceable. A path is:

`[1, 3, 6, 19, 30, 34, 47, 17, 8, 28, 36, 45, 4, 32, 49, 15, 21, 43, 38, 26, 10, 39, 42, 22, 27, 9, 16, 48, 33, 31, 50, 14, 11, 25, 24, 40, 41, 23, 13, 12, 37, 44, 5, 20, 29, 35, 46, 18, 7, 2]`

With one minor optimization, your code completed on my machine in roughly 3 minutes. As you can see below, I evaluate each pair `i`,`j` only once and a I skip pairs where `i == j`. If you wanted to speed it up further (without any algorithmic refinement), you could parallelize the nested loop with `joblib`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

def is_traceable(G):
    """
    :type G: nx.Graph
    """
    nodes = G.nodes()
    needed = len(nodes)
    for ii, v in enumerate(nodes):
        for w in nodes[(ii+1):]:
            for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, v, w):
                if len(path) == needed:
                    return True, path
    return False

def is_perfect_square(num):
    if np.isclose(num, int(np.sqrt(num))**2):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def get_graph(n):
    nodes = range(1, n + 1)
    graph = nx.Graph()
    graph.add_nodes_from(nodes)
    for i in nodes:
        for j in nodes:
            if i != j and is_perfect_square(i + j):
                graph.add_edge(i, j)
    return graph

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 50
    g = get_graph(n)
    print(is_traceable(g))
```